# can not get response value from SOAP UI using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

i need to generate a values in scale 51.058993 to 54.152632

using this simple script but SOAP UI dont generate any values or alert mssg when i try execute this script.

script:

```
double min = 51.058993
double max = 54.152632
def x = ((Math.random() * ((max - min) * 10 + 1) + min * 10) / 10.0).round(6)
println(x)
```

Comment: SoapUI doesn't have `println()` the way you expect. Use `log.info(x)` instead